# Bash: export not passing variables correctly to parent

Tags: bash, variables, parameter-passing

The variables exported in a child-script are undefined the parent-script (`a.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is the parent script: a.sh
export var="5e-9"
./b.sh var
export result=$res;  # $res is defined and recognized in b.sh
echo "result = ${result}"
```

The child-script (`b.sh`) looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is the child script: b.sh
# This script has to convert exponential notation to SI-notation
var1=$1
value=${!1}
exp=${value#*e}
reduced_val=${value%[eE]*}
if [ $exp -ge -3 ] || [ $exp -lt 0 ]; then SI="m";
elif [ $exp -ge -6 ] || [ $exp -lt -3 ]; then SI="u";
elif[ $exp -ge -9 ] || [ $exp -lt -6 ]; then SI="n";
fi

export res=${reduced_val}${SI}
echo res = $res
```

If I now run the parent using `./a.sh`, the output will be:

```
res = 5n
result = 4n
```

So there is some rounding problem going on here. Anybody any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: I guess you want to do `./b.sh $var`, otherwise you are providing the string "var" to `b.sh` instead of the variable `$var`.

Comment: That's not what `export` is supposed to do. It passes variables to children, there's no way to set variables in the parent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access variable's in `b.sh` use `source` instead :

```
source b.sh var
```

It should give what you wanted.

Comment: is this the same as using `. ./b.sh var`?

Comment: `. b.sh` to be appropriate. `./` just points to current directory.

Comment: I did seem to encounter a problem. I only want the variables that are exported to be passed back to the parent. The other variables defined within the child-script should not influence the parent-variables. Is that also possible?

Comment: I guess that's not possible. A simple workaround would be to rename the colliding variables in the child script.

Comment: Thanks, I added a specific pattern to the pattern to the variables that I only use in child-scripts

Answer (score 3):

Exporting variables in bash includes them in the environment of any child shells (subshells). There is however no way to access the environment of the parent shell.

As far as your problem is concerned, I would suggest writing `$res` only to stdout in `b.sh`, and capturing the output via subshell in `a.sh`, i.e. `result=$( b.sh )`. This approach comes closer to structured programming (you call a piece of code that returns a value) than using shared variables, and it is more readable and less error-prone.

Comment: This works quite nice as long as I use `result=$(./b.sh var)`. Yet in this situation it has to be certain that the result is the only output. Yet in my full code there may be multiple outputs and in that case the answer of @blackSmith is more suitable and more consistently usable.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Jaros' solution is a better approach IMO. You can expand on it to pass any number of variable back to the parent using read:

b.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
var1="var1 stuff"
var2="var2 stuff"
echo "$var1;$var2"
```

a.sh

```
 IFS=";" read -r var1 var2 < <(./b.sh );
 echo "var1=$var1"
 echo "var2=$var2"
```

Comment: I agree this is the better solution. If the output of the child script includes other things than exported variables, then a keyword could be used for the lines exporting a variable (e.g. `EXPORT_VARIABLE var value`) so that the output can be filtered accordingly.